# Independence of max and min of a set of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with cdf $F_X(x)$. Define $U$ and $L$ as $U=\max\{ X_1, \ldots ,X_n\}$ and $L = \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$.

Are $U$ and $L$ independent?

I believe they are I just don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 7):

No, they are not. If we know that $L=x$, then the probability that $U<x$ is zero (while it is well possible that the prior probability was non-zero).

Comment: To be precise, they aren't independent *unless* the distribution of the $X_i$ is degenerate, i.e. the underlying probability space contains an element $x$ with $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

They are not independent because for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
   \Pr\left(L \leqslant y \mid U \leqslant y\right) = 1 
$$
which is not equal $\Pr(L\leqslant y)$ as it would be if $U$ and $L$ were independent.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can actually compute the joint law:

$$
P(x< L, U\le y) = (F(y) - F(x))^n 1_{x<y}
$$

and from that, see that there is no independance.